# how to send an activation code through email? in asp.net mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, email, send, activation-codes

i have button called ask for activation code, when i click on the button it should send an activation code email to the user? what is the best way of doing?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class to send emails in.NET.